# CodeBlocks lib7z linking issue

Tags: c++, c++17, 7zip

I'm using Code::Blocks v20.03 in C++17 compatibility mode, and I am trying to link the bit7z 7zip decompression library to my project. I downloaded the latest build of bit7z(bit7z-v4.0.5-mingw8.1.0_x64.7z) and tried to follow the tutorial on the site to link everything. I have the library downloaded to my E:\ drive, and did the usual library linker stuff, but C::B is complaining that it can't find the library.

Here are all my linker and directory settings:

Linker:

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lbit7z -loleaut32
```

Compiler directory:

```
E:\SDL2-2.28.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
E:\bit7z\include\bit7z
```

Linker directory:

```
E:\SDL2-2.28.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
E:\bit7z\lib
```

C::B finds SDL2 just fine, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong that it can't find bit7z. Is there some step I've missed?

Tried following the tutorial as close as possible, tried reinstalling bit7z, tried adding 7z.dll.a to the lib folder.

Expected that if I followed the download and install instructions for bit7z, and followed C::B's library link instructions, that it could find the bit7z library.

Comment: What is the actual error message? Might be a good idea to put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the 7z issue alone.

Comment: The compiler gives the following error:
`||=== Build: Debug in launcher (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lbit7z|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|`
I will create an MRE tomorrow after work and see if I can get bit7z to work.

Comment: `-lbit7z` will look for `libbit7z.a`, does that file exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue thanks to this thread here with a helpful answer from the library author himself:
[Unresolved External Symbol while trying to use bit7z library C++ / Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895431/unresolved-external-symbol-while-trying-to-use-bit7z-library-c-qt/74003596#74003596)

I wasn’t linking all the way to the library subdirectory, and I was calling `-lbit7z` instead of `-lbit7z64`.

The following settings fixed my issue:

linker:

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lbit7z64 -loleaut32
```

Compiler directory:

```
E:\SDL2-2.28.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
E:\bit7z\include\bit7z\x64
```

Linker directory:

```
E:\SDL2-2.28.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
E:\bit7z\lib
```